# Volume name changes automatically

Tags: disk-volume

I have 5 HDDs, /dev/sd[abcde]. After reboot my system volume is sometimes /dev/sda and sometimes /dev/sde.

How can I fix this so that's always the same?

Comment: Any detail on the hardware? If this problem persists, look into mounting devices by UUID

Comment: What detail do you need? There are 4x 2TB disc and 1x 250 GB running on Debian 6. Mounting by UUID is already enabled but its annoying.

Comment: Ignore the symbolic label and use a UUID or a filesystem you define.

Comment: My problem is that all my system partitions are mounted by UUID - fine. The other disks should become a Raid-Z - therefore no UUID exists since there is no ext partition on it.

Comment: The disks are all internal SATA disks on the same controller?

Comment: Yes, they are..

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using `e2label` (for example, [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-debian-fedora-mount-partition-label/) is quite good).

This way, you can label your devices such as `boot`, `backup`, `apps` and mount based on these labels (so it won't matter which order you plug your drives in, or what order they appear to be detected in).